# How can I disable PXE network booting through vSphere on a virtual machine running on VMware ESXi 4.1.0 as host?

Tags: networking, virtualization, vmware, vmware-server, esxi

How can I disable PXE network booting through vSphere on a virtual machine running on VMware ESXi 4.1.0 as host?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

boot from a cd drive... be sure to "power on startup" the drive on your VM

Answer (score 0):

add a cd drive to the VM........... and change the boot order in the bios!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change only the boot order in the bios of the VM, the cd drives of the previous answers have with this nothing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the BIOS and disable PXE boot.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `.vmx` file (located in your virtual machine folder) and add the following line to the bottom of it:

```
ethernet0.opromsize="0"
```

OR

```
ethernet0.opromsize="TRUE"
```